How to hide a control node upon mouse click outside of it
I have a control node, let's call it Menu. It is a popup with some UI elements. It is shown when a button is pressed. It should be closed (hidden or maybe freed) when the player clicks anywhere outside of it.
How to implement this?
My current approach: Add a PanelContainer with an empty stylebox, make it span the whole screen, and position it behind the popup. This is so that mouse clicks outside of the Menu can be registered and not consumed by any other control node. When it consumes the mouse click, it emits a signal which is used to hide/free the Menu and itself.
This works, but is a bit cumbersome and feels like a work-around.

You are going to need to catch the click event somewhere - either with a UI control or just as part of the standard event handling - from that perspective any solution is going to be a workaround since you are going to have to route the click back to close/dismiss the UI. You can probably clean it up a bit by formalizing the pattern.

Ok, but what would "standard event handling" mean here?
